# MySQL - Sort asc with text in the begginig

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a MySQL table with 'address' field with addresses in format:

```
StreetName 1
StreetName 10
StreetName 34
Streetname 8
```

How to make a MySQL Query that will resault:

```
StreetName 1
Streetname 8
StreetName 10
StreetName 34
```

Simple "order by address" doesn't work in this case, because "StreetName 8" is AFTER "StreetName 34".

Answer (score 0):

If the street name wont have any spaces, this should work

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(address,LOCATE(' ',address)+1) AS UNSIGNED)
```

**Update:** If the street names have spaces, but the numbers are always at the end with a space preceding them eg. `S Av 2`, `N Pike Street 5` etc, you can try this..

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(address,' ', -1) AS UNSIGNED)
```

I have also assumed that the street numbers will be unsigned(not negative). A [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1610e3/1) for you..

Comment: but it has spaces, so this solution is not good :(

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. Is there a posibility to create new column with will only have street numbers and another, without it? Then I could sort first by street name, then, by street nuber by simple "order by 'streetname' asc, 'streetnumber', asc

Comment: May I know why it doesn't work?

Comment: it displayed only street names without numbers in address field, sorting also was strange, without any rule